# Why does IValidatableObject method Validate() have a parameter for validationContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC I have the ability to have a model inherit from IValidatableObject, in which case I must implement `IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)`

Why does this method have the parameter validationContext?  I can refer to members using keyword 'this'?  Is there a benefit to using validationContext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ValidationContext` provides additional properties and methods that can be used for more complex validation that might be associated with values that are not part of your model. For example you might want to validate that a property of your model is unique in in a database, so you could inject a service (that implements `System.IServiceProvider`) into the `ValidationContext` constructor, or add a dictionary containing additional values used for validation using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd538582(v=vs.110).aspx), which you might then use in a [Validator.TryValidateValue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateobject(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

And example of adding an `IServiceProvider` to `ValidationContext` in a mvc project is shown in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/tugberkugurlu/3848723).

As a side note, implementing `IValidatableObject` will only give you server side validation, and you really should be using validation attributes that implement `IClientValidatable` to give you client side validation as well. If the in-built attributes are not suitable, then you can create your own as discussed in [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2).

Comment: Valuable answer.  Thanks for the link to the complete guide to ASP.NET MVC3 validation.  Very insightful.  I especially like remote validators.  Also, I never knew IValidatableObject.Validate will NOT get called unless the other validators were successful.  As described in the complete guide, this may lead to poor user experiences.  The user may correct errors only to get more errors.  I use Unity as my IoC framework.  Trying to figure out how to implement IServiceProvider using Unity.  If you have any examples of simple IServiceProvider implementations using Unity that would be awesome!